# Find out filed update procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, profiling

currently I am working inside a company with a really messy information system. I mean: the system administrator does not have a full understanding of all the procedures and processes that daily run on the net they are working on!
We have this kind of problem: every day at 5 am, a filed in a table on one database (SQl Server 2008) is updated without any sense.
My question is: if we exclude the SQL profiler, there are other way to discover major details on the procedure, process, user or application that update the field?

Comment: Why are you excluding the profiler? Do you want to find the application doing this or not?

Comment: Two reason: I does not have permission to run profiler and I wish to discover alternative way (if exists :)

Comment: What's the second reason? If you don't have permission someone in the organization must, no?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. But sometimes internal policy, contract agreement or a lot of other things make impossible ask and receive!

Answer (score 0):

You can try these tools.

[Profiler for Microsoft SQL Server 2005/2008](http://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/TSQL-profiler.aspx